# error while installing samba on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, samba

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba : Depends: python-samba but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libldb1 (>= 0.9.21) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: attr
         Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

Samba depends on other packages that are not installed or they are installed at a different version from what Samba needs. Ubundu has something like a trouble to get the thing going so you will need to do the math manually.

For this and other issues use a Package Manager called Synaptic. It is a graphical tool and can be downloaded and installed graphically!.

Use Synaptic to install the dependencies. Use your mind. Click on search and attempt to install the stated dependent packages starting from "samba-libs". You do this by simply searching / ticking / Applying. Only clicking. No commands necessary. Read the warnings about new dependencies of the dependencies and try to install what you can.  If you get stuck, try with next dependency especially the ones you got when you attempted to install samba.

It won't take long. Play around and you will finally get through and be able to install Samba normally using:

"sudo apt-get install samba"

Take care